# ANTLR 4 : How to know the existence of subpart in rule

Tags: antlr4

I have this code :

```
varDeclaration
    :   type ID ('=' expression)? ';' 
    ;
```

So, not always `('=' expression)` exist. But, sometimes, I want to process this part, but don't know it exist or not in this context. I'm using ANTLR 4 (and often using Listener), how can I know this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your listener (`exitVarDeclaration`) or visitor (`visitVarDeclaration`) check whether `ctx.expression() == null`. If null, then `('=' expression)` didn't exist. If non-null, then it did exist.