# how to handle conditionally existing components in action code?

Tags: antlr4

This is another problem I am facing while migrating from antlr3 to antlr4. This problem is with the java action code for handling conditional components of rules. One example is shown below.

The following grammar+code worked in antlr3. Here, if the unary operator is not present, then a value of '0' is returned, and the java code checks for this value and takes appropriate action.

```
exprUnary returns [Expr e]
    : (unaryOp)? e1=exprAtom
          {if($unaryOp.i==0) $e = $e1.e;
           else $e = new ExprUnary($unaryOp.i, $e1.e);
          }
    ;
unaryOp returns [int i]
    : '-'   {$i = 1;}
    | '~'   {$i = 2;}
    ;
```

In antlr4, this code results in a null pointer exception during a run, because 'unaryOp' is 'null' if it is not present. But if I change the code like below, then antlr generation itself reports an error:

```
if($unaryOp==null) ...
java org.antlr.v4.Tool try.g4
error(67): missing attribute access on rule reference 'unaryOp' in '$unaryOp'
```

How should the action be coded for antlr4?

Another example of this situation is in if-then-[else] - here $s2 is null in antlr4:

```
ifStmt returns [Stmt s]
    : 'if' '(' e=cond ')' s1=stmt ('else' s2=stmt)?
           {$s = new StmtIf($e.e, $s1.s, $s2.s);}
    ;
```

NOTE: question [16392152](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392152) provides a solution to this question with listeners, but I am not using listeners, my requirement is for this to be handled in the action code.

Comment: error: unknown attribute 'tree' for rule 'unaryOp' in '$unaryOp.tree'

Comment: That magic worked!! Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Cool, just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two potential ways to correct this:

1. The "ANTLR 4" way to do it is to create a listener or visitor instead of placing the Java code inside of actions embedded in the grammar itself. This is the only way I would even consider solving the problem in my own grammars.
2. If you still use an embedded action, the most efficient way to check if the item exists or not is to access the `ctx` property, e.g. `$unaryOp.ctx`. This property resolves to the `UnaryOpContext` you were assuming would be accessible by `$unaryOp` by itself.

Comment: Thanks. I am constrained to not use the listener/visitor approach in this legacy project. But why would the $unaryOp.ctx be more efficient than the $unaryOp.text check?

Comment: `$unaryOp.text` is equivalent to `$unaryOp.ctx.getText()` when `unaryOp` is not null. The `getText()` method iterates over all tokens in the block parsed by `unaryOp`, concatenating the text of each one to produce the result. If you are not actually using the string, it's pointless to create it.

Comment: Thanks. Since this is a more comprehensive answer, I will accept this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR expects you access an attribute. Try its `text` attribute instead: `$unaryOp.text==null`

Comment: I have tested this and it works for me. But I would also like to see a reply from 280Z28, for a comparison between your solution and his.